# How to verify an invisible element on the Web Page

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-web-driver

I am testing a link using webdriver, but i am not able to locate where that link(element) is there on the webpage. How to detect that where the given element is present on the webpage?
Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

From the [Getting Started Documentation](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted), you can use:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("elementName"));
```

Where `elementName` is the name of the element that you are looking for.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding how this answer constitutes a down-vote.

Answer (score 0):

Use Ctrl+Shift+I in chrome browser, and try to find that element in the developer's console using Ctrl+F. (You will have to click developer console's screen first before you do Ctrl+F)

Answer (score 0):

U can check the presence of element by using explicit wait

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element))
```

it will return true or false, boolean value can be used.